# Set and remove alarms while avoiding new intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am setting an alarm with

```
    Bundle Resids = new Bundle();
    Resids.putInt("ResID",ResID);
    Resids.putLong("Time",Time);
    intent.putExtras(Resids);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int)Time, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, Time, pendingIntent);
```

I used to set the `intent = new Intent(context, BRClass.class);` before `Bundle Resids = new Bundle();` but then, because there was a new intent each time for a new alarm, I could not use `alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);` as I did not know which `intent` to use in `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int)Time, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`.

With the current implementation, only the first alarm is set and no other.

How to cancel alarms being created with the above code? An array with intents?

Comment: You'll have to save all ```(int)Time``` somewhere and then call ```cancel``` with newly constructed ```PendingIntent``` with each ```(int)Time```.

Comment: Using which intent? One that is globally initialized and used over and over or a new one each time?

Comment: Every intent is just a set of some data, you don't need to store intent instance. Every time you need the same intent as somewhere in the past then construct it with the same arguments. In your case, it will be ```new Intent(context, BRClass.class)```. The only thing that must be saved is the request code ```(int)Time```. Others can be constructed every time you need it.

Comment: Ah, there are extras also. Then save all of them too.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an alarm with the `AlarmManager`, it will automatically cancel any other alarm that has been set with a **matching `PendingIntent`**. This means that if you want to have multiple alarms set, you must ensure that each `PendingIntent` is unique.

To ensure that a `PendingIntent` is unique, you need to ensure that at least one of the following is unique:

- The `requestCode` used when calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`
- The ACTION in the `Intent`
- The DATA in the `Intent`

Please note that "extras" are not considered when determining if 2 `PendingIntent`s "match".

Also, your `requestCode` is created by casting a `long` value to an `int`. This is bad because the `long` value will not fit in an `int` and you will lose some bits of the value. This won't guarantee that your `requestCode`s are unique. You should convert your `long` value to another value that will actually fit in an `int` to ensure unique `requestCode`s.